# Unable to launch Playwright from Flask (With Nginx)

Tags: nginx, flask, python-3.8, playwright-python

I need to launch playwright from Flask to perform some automation. It works fine when I run it using `python app.py` but when I try to deploy it using uwsgi and nginx, I get this error

```
    with sync_playwright() as p:
  File "venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/playwright/sync_api/_context_manager.py", line 83, in __enter__
    playwright = self._playwright
AttributeError: 'PlaywrightContextManager' object has no attribute '_playwright'
```

I am following the tutorial from this [digitalocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04). I have deployed other Flask apps using the same tutorial and it works fine without playwright.

I am using Python 3.8 and Flask==2.1.2, playwright==1.22.0 version.